# Show xml in TextArea using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer

The following works in FireFox and Chrome, but not in IE -

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test IE</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button onClick="fTest2()">test textarea</button>
<br />
<textarea rows="4" cols="50"  id="log" >  textHolder . . .  </textarea>

<script type="text/javascript" >

var currentLine = 3;
var strXml = "<xmlString id='misssing' >" + currentLine + "</xmlString>";

    function fTest2() {
      $('#log').html(strXml);
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found it -

I had to use

```
$('#log').val(strXml);
```

instead of

```
$('#log').html(strXml);
```